# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 11: invalid start byte

Tags: python, numpy

i am trying to read this xlsx file

```
tran=np.loadtxt("s.xlsx",delimiter=",")
x_train=tran[:,1:45]
y_train=tran[:,45]
test=np.loadtxt("s.xlsx",delimiter=",")
x_test=test[:,45]
y_test=test[:,:]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Example_1.py", line 11, in <module>
    tran=np.loadtxt("s.xlsx",delimiter=",")
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1086, in loadtxt
    first_line = next(fh)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 314, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 11: invalid start byte
```

but when i try running the program i get this error

Comment: `loadtxt` is for a `csv` produced from a `xlsx`, not the `xlsx` itself.

Comment: Oh okay I will try converting the file to csv